# A continuous random walk of length 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, convolution, random-walk

Suppose one starts at origo in in the plane and takes $N$ steps of length $1/N$ in a random direction, what is the distribution of the resulting distance from origo as $N$ approaches infinity?
For one step, the distribution along the x-axis is $1/(N\pi\sqrt{1-x^2})$, I wanted to take the convolution of $N$ such functions and then take the limit but the integrals seemed hopeless, is there an easy way to find the distribution? If not, I am happy with just the answer.

Comment: For the limiting distribution use the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: @GEdgar How can the limiting distribution be gaussian if its zero for distances above 1?

Comment: There shouldn't be an $N$ in the distribution for one step?

Comment: Limiting distribution for $N$ steps as $N \to \infty$.  To get something non-trivial in the limit, you need to take $N$ steps of size 1/$\sqrt{N}$ or something like that.  It is true that the exact distribution for $N$ steps is "hopeless".  Two steps gives us a distribution with Bessel functions in it.   Borwein, Borwein, & Wan have some work on 3 and 4 steps, as I recall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps somewhat surprisingly, the limiting distribution is the one where the distance is certain to be $0$. As GEdgar pointed out, you can apply the central limit theorem. Along either axis, you're taking the average of $N$ identically distributed steps, and by the central limit theorem the resulting marginal distribution along either axis becomes approximated by a Gaussian with variance proportional to $1/N$. Thus the variance goes to zero and the shape becomes Gaussian, so the marginal distribution along either axis converges to a delta distribution, and thus so does the two-dimensional distribution, and hence also that of the distance.